Why are there duplicates of video devices?
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 and now there are two video devices under /dev for each one plugged in.
Here is the output of v4l2-ctl.
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Razer Kiyo Pro (usb-0000:0c:00.3-2):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/media0

Live Streamer CAM 313: Live Str (usb-0000:0c:00.4-1):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media1

The duplicate video devices do not work. All you can do is query the capabilities.
Is this a configuration error?
What are these devices for?
I just did a check on my laptop also running Ubuntu 24.04 and the duplicates are there too.

lsusb with a bunch of -vs (-vvvvv) will show details about what those are about,
Those are not duplicates. the first one is for the device itself and the second one provides metadata (link uses v41 as an example) from the first device.

All you can do is query the capabilities... What are these devices for?

Like you said: the second one provides metadata.
